# resize html reponsive template email

Tags: html, css

I am coding email template(Email marketing).
User can upload html template and select to send mail
I want resize html reponsive on my website like gmail?
How to Resize html element:img,text,table?

**view on Gmail with Mobile**

[image]

**View On my website with Mobile**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the html/css code to be able to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and in order to fix this I found two approaches:

1) Activating the ***Request desktop version***, under the mobile browser settings:

- [How to request desktop version of a Web site in Chrome for Android](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-request-desktop-version-of-a-web-site-in-chrome-for-android/)
- [How to Disable the Mobile Version of a Website on Your iPhone](https://www.howtogeek.com/176932/how-to-disable-the-mobile-version-of-a-website-on-your-phone/)

2) But I just wanted to do this automatically, when my website load in Mobile browser without making the extra steps to set the **Request desktop version**, and this link provided me the instructions to fix the issue:

[Responsive design with “**switch to desktop site**” option](https://leavesofcode.net/2013/07/08/responsive-design-with-switch-to-desktop-site-option/)